# Kafka streams app is killed after processing 90.4 kb of data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am learning Kafka streams and created a simple Kafka stream app, which gets the JSON data from one topic, converts it into an object, does some operations with its fields, and sends it into another topic like that:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bootstrapServer = "localhost:9092";
        final Properties streamsConfiguration = getStreamConfiguration(bootstrapServer);
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        sampleProcessor(streamsBuilder);
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }

    private static void sampleProcessor(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> rectangleKafka = streamsBuilder.stream("sample_topic");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        rectangleKafka.mapValues(x -> {
            try {
                Rectangle rectangle = objectMapper.readValue(x, Rectangle.class);
                rectangle.setArea(rectangle.width * rectangle.height);
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rectangle);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }).to("calculated_value");
    }

    static Properties getStreamConfiguration(final String bootstrapServers) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "sample_app");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 10240);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/var/lib/kafka-streams/");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the app stops processing data right after it does exactly 90.4 kb of data, which is roughly 100 records. It was working okay-ish just yesterday and processed 5 GB of data out of 14, and then it suddenly stopped working, every time I try to run it, it hits the wall with this limit.
I've tried to find a reason for this problem all day, but I don't seem to understand what to even look for, and I can't find any useful info in search engines. I am considering deleting every bit of Kafka from my PC and trying to start anew, but before doing so I hope to find someone here who might have already solved a problem like this one before. Will appreciate any help, thank you!

PS. Strangely, but there is no error that I can google, the app simply dies after a few seconds with exit code 0.

Comment: Perhaps your JVM is running out of memory? Have you tried running the `kafka-streams-application-reset` command and trying again?

Comment: That helped, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Partially :( Now it processes 6 Gb out of 14 and after that crashes still. I've raized max memory (xmx) for jvm to 16 Gb, but it makes no differnce.

Comment: In my experience, Xmx beyond 8G causes really long GC pauses for large objects, so isn't recommended. Plus, your code isn't stateful, so doesn't really need a large heap. Does it just stop cleanly; no logs (make sure your logger is in debug mode, for example) or exceptions or non zero exit code?

Comment: Found it! Record batch for partition ____ at offset 10720059 is invalid, cause: Record is corrupt (stored crc = 2656190098, computed crc = 3916787189)

Comment: Great. So, now the only problem is figuring out which broker that partition is stored on... Assuming you have a replication factor higher than one, you could delete the offending log segment, and let it re-replicate from another broker

Comment: I'm learning, so all of the code runs on a single local machine, not sure I can up the replication factor on it